# I can't see my new PSU symbol in Eagle

Tags: power-supply, eaglecad, pins, library

I am new to Eagle having just returned to my hobby after many years and decided to use Eagle.

I need a 1v8 supply net, and so followed the guidance and created my own supply line in my own library.

BUT.... no matter what I do, I can not see the device in the schematic, or in the device preview but I can see the symbol - I have no idea what I have not done, or done incorrectly.

I wanted to define my own PSU symbol rather than just use VCC and VDD as this is recommended practice.

What have I done wrong? Here is a link to a copy of my lbr file that has the symbol and package in it... [Eagle Library file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0-j3aTERfPqM089hXHs0pQCgdr1Qfq0/view?usp=sharing)

[Library file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0-j3aTERfPqM089hXHs0pQCgdr1Qfq0/view?usp=sharing)

I have also added the screen shots of the eagle library manager

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post links to stuff that gives "You need access"!

Comment: Hi Mats, it should be publicly available - I would rather have attached the file, but I couldn't find a way of doing that... is there a better way of sharing this contents?

Comment: Yes, now it is available. And Darn, I couldn't find any errors in the library. But you mention, "so followed the guidance" but there is no link to the guidance?

Comment: Hi Mats, so by guidance I followed the manual section 8.6 (Supply Symbols) that I access through Help->documentation. Sorry I should have mentioned that. Thanks again for help